# Rails + AngularJs + Unable to fetch data using Service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3.2, angular-services

In my AngularJs app with Rails server as backend, I am trying to fetch data using GET method but unable to access the data. Not able to recognize the error.

**AngularCode**

```
var app = angular.module('UserApp', []);
app.controller('LoggedInUserInfoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {            
  $http.get('/LoggedInUserInfo.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.logged_in_users = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // log error
      alert('error');
    });     
});
```

**LoggedInUserInfo ERB Page**

```
<div ng-controller="LoggedInUserInfoCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="logged_in_user in logged_in_users">
    Profile - {{logged_in_user.first_name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**UserController**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def logged_in_user_info
    @user = User.find_by_username(session[:UserName])
    render :json => @user
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
match '/LoggedInUserInfo' => 'users#logged_in_user_info', :via => [:get]
```

**URL: http://example.com/LoggedInUserInfo.json**

```
{"first_name":"UserOne","last_name":"1","primary_email":"user_one@mailinator.com", "user_unique_id":"A001",}
```

**ERROR - at Firefox Console**

> Error: [ng:areq]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/ng/areq?p0=LoggedInUserInfoCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
>   v/<@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:7:443
>   Bb@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:20:62
>   Ua@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:20:241
>   Pd/this.$gethttp://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:68:405
>   K/<@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:55:40
>   q@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:8:363
>   K@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:54:405
>   f@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:48:261
>   f@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:48:261
>   f@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:48:261
>   f@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:48:261
>   f@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:48:261
>   f@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:48:261
>   f@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:48:261
>   f@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:48:261
>   z/<@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:47:374
>   cc/c/http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:19:279
>   Zd/this.$gethttp://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:112:342
>   Zd/this.$gethttp://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:113:116
>   cc/c/<@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:19:237
>   d@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:36:27
>   cc/c@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:19:217
>   cc@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:19:349
>   Xc@http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:18:452
>   @http://example.com/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:213:356
>   x.Callbacks/c@http://example.com/assets/jquery.js?body=1:5:26028
>   x.Callbacks/p.fireWith@http://example.com/assets/jquery.js?body=1:5:26828
>   .ready@http://example.com/assets/jquery.js?body=1:5:3320
>   q@http://example.com/assets/jquery.js?body=1:5:715

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?,and have you just tried whether www.example.com/LoggedInUserInfo.json is fetching json data first ?

Comment: Yes, I tried and I am getting the JSON

Comment: and so you are now just getting an alert('error') ?

Comment: NO, I think that service is not called.

Comment: this is silly, but just try adding double quotes ..$http.get("/LoggedInUserInfo.json")

Comment: Ya buddy but I tried that as well. NO success.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62489/discussion-between-rubyist-and-rahul-sambari).

Comment: You are getting this error as per console logs you gave "Argument 'LoggedInUserInfoCtrl' is not a function, got undefined" which means angular is not able to find `LoggedInUserInfoCtrl` method. Have you wrapped your ng-controller div inside a `<div ng-app="App">....</div>`

Comment: Yes ..@Siraj, ng-app="UserApp" is present in application.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

As I gone through alot of changes with services and all. But finally found the actual reason of error.

In other words, I will say silly mistake or addition of code from my own.

Before few hours, I have added one script to show auto-complete related to Blood Group. So that script is disturbing the call of my new method.

I just removed that script and got the output.

Thanks alot to Rahul Sambari and Siraj ...